# UITableViewCell custom delete buttons

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to put my own custom delete buttons on the uitableview cell when it goes into edit mode, similiar to the "+" add button for inserting, just a red "x" in the same position as the "+" button is. how would i do this?

Comment: What's wrong with the standard "-" button?

Comment: the standard '-' button is on the left, when clicked it rings up the delete button. I want to go straight to a custom delete button when in edit mode. and i want this button in the right where the "+" button sits.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement it with using cell `willTransitionToState`.

Like this in CustomTableCell.m：

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state{
    if (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask) {
        customEditBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( -32, 0, 42, self.contentView.height)];
        customEditBtn.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
        [customEditBtn setImage:_image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.contentView addSubview:customEditBtn];

    }
}

- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state{
    [super didTransitionToState:state];
    if (state != UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask) {
        customEditBtn.alpha = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case others ever have this question:
You have to set the `editingAccessoryView` on your `UITablViewCell` to whatever custom `UIView` you want it to be.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: The `editingAccessoryView` is used for "Edit" mode, which is enabled by calling `setEditing:animated` on the cell or on the table. This is not the same as the swipe to reveal the delete function. If you look up the documentation for UITableViewCell's `willTransitionToState:` method, you will see that the "Delete Confirmation" is a different mode to "Showing Edit Control".

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UIButton *btnDelete = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];
[btnDelete setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delet.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonClicked:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.accessoryView = btnDelete;
```

Comment: Isn't AccessoryView on the right side of tableViewCell? Edit control is on the left side.